# Copy data from an open explorer windows, with VB or .bat

Tags: vba, batch-file, copy

I would like to ask you if it's possible (and how), to copy all data from an open explorer window (name or path not known) automatically to another folder? I don't think that this is possible with .bat, but maybe with VB?

Comment: If your process doesn't have ownership of the window then no.

Comment: It might be possible but need a little clarity here. How will you select the `Window`? The reason I ask is if there are multiple windows opened then which one should we pick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a trivial VBA example where I open a web page in Internet Explorer, copy all the text, and place it in a cell. Your question isn't very clear, so I don't know whether this addresses what you want to do, but it can probably help.

**EDIT** Upon re-reading your question I think I confused Explorer with Internet Explorer... So this may not be relevant after all. If so, I will delete this.

```
Dim ex As InternetExplorer
Dim hd As HTMLDocument
Dim s As String

Set ex = New InternetExplorer

With ex
    .Navigate "http://donttrack.us/"
    .Visible = 1
    Set hd = .Document
    s = hd.body.innerText
    Range("A1") = s
End With
```